# Run Test Coverage inside Docker container for Pyspark test cases

Tags: docker, pyspark, test-coverage

I have a pyspark project with few unit test case files

```
test case files
test_testOne.py
test_testcaseTwo.py
```

These test classes are executed inside a docker container. While running the tests inside the container i want to get the test coverage reports also. Therefore I added the following line in my requirements.txt file

```
coverage==6.0.2
```

And inside the docker container I run he following command

```
python -m coverage discover -s path/to/test/files
```

I am getting the following output

```
/opt/conda/bin/python: No module named coverage
```

Can anybody help me to run my tests successfully with test coverage. Please note that all test cases r successfully running inside the container with the following command. But its not generating the test coverage

```
python -m unittest discover -s path/to/test/files
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `coverage` the command:

```sh
python -m unittest discover -s path/to/test/files
```

Becomes:

```sh
coverage run -m unittest discover -s path/to/test/files
```

> As specified in the documentation: [Quick Start](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.1.1/)

Since you are using docker, a good option is to create a volume inside a docker container and when the tests are finished, `coverage` can generate a report and store it on your host machine. Like that you could automate the whole process and save reports.

- Create a volume using `-v` flag when you start a docker container (more info: [Use Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/))
- After the tests, run `coverage html -d /path/to/your/volume/inside/docker` (look in the documentation for more option: [coverage html](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/cmd.html#html-annotation-coverage-html))